# Upvotes that don't count towards the total reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, up-votes

In the time that I've been a member of StackOverflow, I encountered this situation multiple times. However, the only example that I was able to find now was on Programmers.StackExchange. I ask the question here instead of on Programmer's Meta because I think that, because of SO's size, it has bigger impact on SO.

---

Take a look at [this user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/71645/yaniv-aknin?tab=summary). He has a single answer that received 73 upvotes. So his reputation should be 730 or something very close to that assuming that there may be a few downvotes as well.

If you switch to the reputation tab of his profile, you find this:

[image: reputation screenshot]

More specifically: there are 45 upvotes, only 20 of which have a +10 reputation associated with them. So this brings his expected reputation for that day from 450 down to just 200.

Now, the only situation I can think of where this would make sense is if the question is marked as "community wiki". This is however not the case.

**Why are some upvotes not counted for the total reputation ?** Is there some limit if that's your first day or if that particular answer is your first answer ?

Comment: We have a 200 reputation cap from upvotes only. Had it forever. See the linked "duplicate" for details.

Comment: @Oded Huh, didn't know about that one... Thanks for clearing that up.